# Como chamar uma função dentro de outra função?

Tags: funções, elm

Estou fazendo uma atividade, e a atividade pede para chamar uma função dentro de outra função, como consigo fazer isso?

> 2.10 Escrever uma função que retorne o valor de um número elevado à quarta potência. Essa função deve fazer uso de uma outra que calcula o
>   quadrado de um número qualquer.

Poderia simplesmente fazer:

```
module Fe02 exposing (..)

import Html

funcExp x = x^4

main = Html.text (String.fromFloat (funcExp 2))
```

Assim ele me daria como resultado através de servidor `localhost: 16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta chamar uma função a partir da outra:

```
exp2 x = x^2
exp4 x = exp2 (exp2 x)
```

Então, por exemplo:

```
$ elm repl
> exp2 x = x^2
<function> : number -> number
> exp4 x = exp2 (exp2 x)
<function> : number -> number
> exp4 3
81 : number
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado ! Sua resposta foi perfeita e sucinta amigo. Agradecido !!!!

Comment: @Fehlberg, fico feliz em ter ajudado. Abraço.